# how to connect with bluetooth low energy in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I want to connect with ble peripheral.
But my code doesn't call didConect function

this is my code :

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
 let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
            .object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
            as? NSString

        if device?.contains(BEAN_NAME) == true {

            print("Did discover peripheral", peripheral)

            self.bluetoothManager.stopScan()
            self._peripheral = peripheral
            self._peripheral.delegate = self
            central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
}


func centralManager( central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) { //cant call this
        print("connected to \(BEAN_NAME)")
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
```

Logs :

```
BLE service is powered on
Did discover peripheral <CBPeripheral: 0x1740eef00, identifier = 4872623B-F872-443A-8A96-F4E1F84D6841, name = GoDoor in  :), state = disconnected>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your `if` test is passing?  Normally you would save the `identifier` of the device you are interested in rather looking at the advertisement data.

Comment: yes. Logs print "Did discover peripheral" . When I print something after central.connect, it printed in log. Seems like central.connect not executed.@Paulw11

Comment: How is `_peripheral` declared? Have you implemented the `didFailToConnect` delegate method in case your connection is failing?

Comment: now i can do function didConnect peripheral, it was failed because of "_" sign. It must be :
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)

thanks for helping @Paulw11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this.
just need to change :

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
```

into this :

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
```

reference : [Swift 3: Can't connect to peripheral via BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090560/swift-3-cant-connect-to-peripheral-via-ble)

Comment: Good find.  Changed delegate method signatures in Swift 3 have burned me before as well, and despite that I didn't spot this looking at your question.

Answer (score 2):

I created a demo project, which scans for Bluetooth LE devices and displays them in a list:

Check it out on github: [quickies/BluetoothScanner.ios](https://github.com/quickies/BluetoothScanner.ios)

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score -1):

```
      @IBAction func btnConnect(_ sender: UIButton){

        self.appDelegate.bleManager.stopScan()

        self.appDelegate.selectPeripheral = self.arrayPeripheral[sender.tag]

        self.appDelegate.bleManager.connect(self.selectPeripheral, options: nil)

      }
```